# Load the MNIST digit recognition dataset with R and see any results

Tags: r, machine-learning, mnist

In the book "[Machine Learning - A Probabilistic Perspective" by Kevin P. Murphy](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/titles/content/9780262018029_sch_0001.pdf) the first task reads:

> Exercise 1.1 KNN classifier on shuffled MNIST data
>
> Run mnist1NNdemo
> and verify that the misclassification rate (on the first 1000 test
> cases) of MNIST of a 1-NN classifier is 3.8%. (If you run it all on
> all 10,000 test cases, the error rate is 3.09%.) Modify the code so
> that you first randomly permute the features (columns of the training
> and test design matrices), as in shuffledDigitsDemo, and then apply
> the classifier. Verify that the error rate is not changed.

My simple understanding is that the exercise is looking for the 1-NN after loading the files(kNN() in R).

The files:

> train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz:  training set images (9912422 bytes)
>
> train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz:  training set labels (28881 bytes)
>
> t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz:   test set images (1648877 bytes)
>
> t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz:   test set labels (4542 bytes)

are taken from the [The MNIST DATABASE](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/)

I found a [popular template](https://gist.github.com/brendano/39760) for loading the files:

```
# for the kNN() function 
library(VIM)
load_mnist <- function() {
  load_image_file <- function(filename) {
   ret = list()
    f = file(filename,'rb')
    readBin(f,'integer',n=1,size=4,endian='big')
    ret$n = readBin(f,'integer',n=1,size=4,endian='big')
    nrow = readBin(f,'integer',n=1,size=4,endian='big')
    ncol = readBin(f,'integer',n=1,size=4,endian='big')
    x = readBin(f,'integer',n=ret$n*nrow*ncol,size=1,signed=F)
    ret$x = matrix(x, ncol=nrow*ncol, byrow=T)
    close(f)
    ret
  }
  load_label_file <- function(filename) {
    f = file(filename,'rb')
    readBin(f,'integer',n=1,size=4,endian='big')
    n = readBin(f,'integer',n=1,size=4,endian='big')
    y = readBin(f,'integer',n=n,size=1,signed=F)
    close(f)
    y
  }
  train <<- load_image_file("train-images.idx3-ubyte")
  test <<- load_image_file("t10k-images.idx3-ubyte")
   
  train$y <<- load_label_file("train-labels.idx1-ubyte")
  test$y <<- load_label_file("t10k-labels.idx1-ubyte")  
}

show_digit <- function(arr784, col=gray(12:1/12)) {
  image(matrix(arr784, nrow=28)[,28:1], col=col)
}
```

According to the comment, in the command line this should work:

```
  # Error "Error in matrix(arr784, nrow = 28) : object 'train' not found"
  show_digit(train$x[5,])
```

The question is how can I use the show_digit function ?

---

**Edit** Remove extra question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I figured out for the problem:

First run the whole file in R Studio or ESS, then call the `load_mnist()` from the console. 
After that execute `show_digit(train$x[3,])` in the console again and it works.

Finding the KNN classifier can be done on the whole data set: 
 `a <- knn(train, test, train$y)` but it would be a very slow process.

Predictions for the result can be done like `table(test$y, a)`, test$y is predicted, a is the actual result.